# Open a web link with in the app itself in jquery mobile

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I want to open a url(ex. www.google.com) in jquery mobile android app.
I want to open it with in the context of the app itself. i dont want to open a diffrent browser to launch it on the click of the link or button. i want to open it with in the app.
is it possible. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution [here](https://gist.github.com/1725083):

```
function openInWebView(url)
{
    var anchor = document.createElement('a');
    anchor.setAttribute('href', url);

    var dispatch = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents')
    dispatch.initEvent('click', true, true);

    anchor.dispatchEvent(dispatch);
}
```

Then call the function like this in your app:

```
openInWebView('http://google.com')
```

Comment: thanks daniel.auener, i tried it but it didn't work. it always opens browser to open any link

Comment: If you add some of your code to your question I could build a test and find a solution...

Comment: Thank you daniel.auener for your post. This was exactly what i needed